# How can I programatically remove folder from Finder's Favorites?

Tags: macos, finder, command-line

I installed one app which adds special folder to my Favorites sidebar in Finder. I like the app, but I don't like polluting the sidebar. Unfortunately, the app doesn't allow me to turn off the behavior and even if I manually remove the folder, it appears again after some time (didn't do any special tests though whether it's after restart or when...).

My idea is that if I could come with some bash command to remove this folder from Finder's sidebar, I could put it to `.bash_profile` so it gets executed quite often. I'd fight with the same weapons - from time to time, I'd just remove the folder if present. The question is - is there some command?

I looked for it, but couldn't find any clues. Is there e.g. some text or XML file with Favorites listed I could programatically edit in bash?

Comment: Does right click, 'remove from sidebar' not work? Is that what reappears; it's not clear how you 'manually removed' it.

Comment: What app is in question. If it adds itself back in, this is really about modifying that app since your script and the app will then just engage in a tug of war contest.

Comment: The app is [iDrive Sync](http://idrive.com/), sort of Dropbox. "Manually removed it" means the right click. I can't modify the app, so the tug of war contest is my only option I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the item and drag it out of the sidebar. Pause for a moment and a little cloud will appear under the cursor. Release the cursor. The cloud will disappear and the item will be gone from the sidebar.

Otherwise, if it keeps coming back, look in the preferences for iDrive to see if it can be disabled.

Comment: According to the OP manual removal doesn't stick.